# How can I search a record from a Txt file with large amount record in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, streamreader

I had 10000+ unicode record in my txt file, i using this function for search record from the Txt File:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> myLookupTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     private void LoadFile(){

    var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("datatxt.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream,System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);

                string line;
                char[] spaceSeparator = new char[] { ',' 
                string[] result;

                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    result = line.Split(spaceSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    myLookupTable.Add(result[0],result[1]);
                }
    }
```

It said "Value does not fall within the expected range." from "myLookupTable.Add(result[0],result[1]);"

Anyone know what is the reason of this error and how can i solve it?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is there any guaranty that: result = line.Split(spaceSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None); returning 2 results, i mean result[0] and result[1] are not null?

Comment: yes ,two results would be return...when the record decrease to >100 ,this function work fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
myLookupTable.Add(result[0],result[1]);
```

you may use

```
if(!myLookupTable.ContainsKey(result[0]))
{
    myLookupTable.Add(result[0],result[1]);
}
else
{
   //You have to implement this based on your application business rules
}
```

Comment: sorry..I am not skilled in programming ,may you  
annotate for your answer?? many thanks!

Comment: just replace the first line I highlighted in my answer with second part in your code.